# How can I styling 2 <form> tags with same ID and differrent action attribute or url?

Tags: html, css, forms

```
<form id="user-register-form" class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/send-resume" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<form id="user-register-form" class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/addcompany" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Hello
I have 2 forms in two defferrent page `url` and with same ID and different `url` page . these forms have not any other differrent class BUT i want to add `css` style and handle these two forms separately.I guess can control css styling of these forms with `action="/send-resume"` and `action="/addcompany"`  perperty. These action `parametrs` is the `url` of pages.

**How can I control 2  tags with same ID and differrent action perpperty (different page url)? Is any way for control a html tag with url of thats page or action parametr?**

I only Can handle this forms by `css` . not `php` and not html.
thank you for your helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS Attribute selector to control the different form actions

```html
<style>
#user-register-form[action="/addcompany"] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

#user-register-form[action="/send-resume"] { 
    background-color: red;
}
</style>


<form id="user-register-form" class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/addcompany" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
Add company form
</form>

<form id="user-register-form" class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/send-resume" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
Send resume form
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Css attribute selector :

```
form[action="/send-resume"]{
// style you want
}

form[action="/addcompany"]{
// style you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```css
form[action="/one"] {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="/one">First</form>
<form action="/second">Second</form>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes